# Ubuntu does not load from USB

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, uefi

I have saved an image of ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS  in a USB drive using rufus as explained [here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-ubuntu-20-04)

My computer is Iiyama desktop

I have modified the drive sequence so that it boots from the USB

however instead of [this figure](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/try-ubuntu-20.04.png) to let me run or install ubuntu, I get the GNU GRUB screen telling me to boot from

- Ubuntu
- Ubuntu(safe graphics)
- OEM install (for manufactureres)
- Boot from next volume
- UEFI Firmware settings

If I press Boot from next volume I got a black screen with

```
>>Start PXE over IPv4
>> Start PXE over Ipv6
```

What should I do now to boot from the USB drive?

EDIT: There must be something wrong with the way I wrote the image.
I have tried a different USB with ubuntu 18 and I got a *different GNU GRUB* this time with

- Try Ubuntu without installing
- Install Ubuntu
- OEM install
- Check disc for defects

Selecte "Try" and I am back to the black screen

EDIT2:
Nope it is not the image since it works in a different computer.
It must be the Nvidia graphics card I have then....

EDIT 3. initrd gets executed and that is where it stops.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu (20.04.x LTS)? How did you save the image (tool/method)? Which computer (brand name and model)? Which boot mode UEFI or BIOS (alias CSM alias legacy mode)? Secure boot? -- Please help us help you by editing your question to add this information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Comment: Thanks for the details. Please add model number of the computer. -- It is normal to get the bullet list that you show in the question. What happens when you select 'Ubuntu'? That would the the main choice. 'Boot from next volume' means to boot from another drive, which is probably not what you want (and in your case the computer does not find any other bootable drive).

Comment: I don't understand what that "Ubuntu" means. Does that mean Ubuntu from the USB?? RIght now if I select that it goes to a black screen

Comment: Yes, that is what it should do. I suggest that you select 'DD-mode' in Rufus and use a cloning method instead of extraction.

Comment: I added some findings I did. With a ubuntu 18 USB stick it works .... mmm I selected try and it is black again....(><)

Comment: Please tell us also about the graphics chip/card in the computer. There may be a problem with the graphics driver. If problems with graphics, please try the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset`.

Comment: Nvidia GTX 1080Ti GP102

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115334/discussion-between-sudodus-and-kansairobot).

Comment: @KansaiRobot, Please visit the chat room according to the comment above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: That is a huge resource. I haven't tried all but what I have does not solve my issue