# What comes after initrd /casper/initrd

Tags: boot, grub2

I am having problems booting in Ubuntu.
I went in Grub to the following screen

[image: error]

as you can see the last line is `echo "ready"`. Well it got printed, then stop.
My question is what comes after the execution of `initrd /casper/initrd`?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to do some hands-free installation with preseed file... can you elaborate (edit your question), what you are trying to accomplish and what you have done so far. E.g. the full line behind `linux` would be interesting

Comment: For debugging: remove `quite` and `splash` from the cmdline

Comment: removed already. Also put `no splash`. etc. The thing is after `initrd /casper/initrd` (and the echo) it stops

Comment: @SimonSudler Trying to solve my problem : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285549/ubuntu-does-not-load-from-usb

Comment: My question here is *what comes next* after these lines are executed?

Comment: Nothing... the configuration is fine. Kernel + Initram disk will boot your system

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment. Nothing comes next? After these are executed the process should go somewhere so that ubuntu gets booted right? I ask this to understand what is failing

Comment: remove the `quite` and `splash`, then you can see what is going on... it is possible, that the system boots and stops with some error message. The "initrd" and "ready" echos will be displayed by grub. They have nothing to do with the linux boot process.

Comment: That configuration appears to be from a live cd, not an installed Ubuntu. Don't you have some media booting instead of you drive?

Comment: I am running from a USB drive with ubuntu

Comment: I managed to boot by removing quite and splash and adding `acpi=off` but now ubuntu does not recognize my hard drive :(

Comment: In Ubuntu Live USB only `  }  ` comes after `initrd /casper/initrd` in other flavors or versions `.lz`  has come after, ie `initrd /casper/initrd.lz`. In installed systems other things are possible such as `initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-47-generic` depending on the kernel.