# USB Ubuntu installer does not recognize my hard drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, hard-drive

I tried to install ubuntu from USB and failed.
Investigating why, I found (in Disks) that Ubuntu (running from USB) cannot see my hard drive. It only sees the USB, a CD/DVD drive and a 2.1Gb Loop device

I am inside this with a not normal way of booting. Is there any way to sense my HD?

(`fdisk -l` cannot see the drive either)

Comment: do you see your hard drive in bios (on the boot sequence for example)? can you check if the hard disk / ssd is properly connected and supplied with power? is it a laptop? a desktop? an airplane?

Comment: it is a desktop... Ok I have suffered to be able to boot this thing, but I guess I will go to bios again...

Comment: please tell me how can I check that?

Comment: Do you want to keep Window (and install Ubuntu alongside)? Or do you want to replace Windows and have only Ubuntu?

Comment: if you are there,  you can give also more details about the configuration: specifications, is a new pc, did it had other os installed before, etc

Comment: I want only ubuntu. I am using a new HD that I installed. I have a huge problem with the Nvidia card that does not let me boot normally. I am not sure if there was something installed in the HD but I want to wipe it out

Comment: @Vlad, see also [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285549/ubuntu-does-not-load-from-usb#1285549).

Comment: Try with AHCI according to ToDo's answer. If you cannot see the hard disk drive at all (for example with `fdisk`) from Ubuntu, something is seriously wrong. Can you see the HDD with an older version (18.04)?

Comment: *"I am using a new HD that I installed"* Did you see the drive after installing it? It could be a faulty connection.

Comment: mmm it seems it can not see the drive. It only sees HL-DT-ST DVDRA ATAPI which I suppose is a DVD. I will open the PC and verify... (sigh)

Comment: than this is a hardware problem. Can you try the hard disk in another computer?

Comment: Thanks. I solved this problem by reattaching the disk. Now I only got the other problems left (not rebooting, failing to install ubuntu etc) but at least this one is solved

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution :-)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with my laptop which I solved by changing one BIOS setting.

In BIOS System Configuration set Sata Operation to "AHCI".

Comment: I am checking this now Where can I see the Sata? I am searching in the BIOS screen

Comment: @KansaiRobot, Only you can see it, because each computer (brand and model) has its own UEFI/BIOS system. You must search in the menus until you find it.